# Why the indexing affects a complete array instead of one item ? (c#)

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, indexing, initialization

I have faced with a strange behavior in c#. I created a int[][] array like this:

```
int[][] m_dist = Enumerable.Repeat(Enumerable.Repeat(-1, m.Length).ToArray(), m.Length).ToArray();
```

**Array looks like this:**

-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,

-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,

-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,

-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,

-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,

-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,

Later on when I tried to modify a single array element I was supraised because not only one item was changed  but a complete int[] array:

```
 m_dist[1][1] = 0;
```

**Output was:**

-1,0,-1,-1,-1,-1,

-1,0,-1,-1,-1,-1,

-1,0,-1,-1,-1,-1,

-1,0,-1,-1,-1,-1,

-1,0,-1,-1,-1,-1,

-1,0,-1,-1,-1,-1,

I suspected that something happens during the array creation therefore I simplified it like this:

```
 //int[][] m_dist = Enumerable.Repeat(Enumerable.Repeat(-1, m.Length).ToArray(), m.Length).ToArray();
 
 int[][] m_dist = new int[m.Length][];
 for (int i = 0; i < m_dist.Length; i++)
 {
    m_dist[i] = new int[m.Length];
    for (int j = 0; j < m_dist[i].Length; j++)
    {
       m_dist[i][j] = -1;
    }
 }
```

With this kind of initialization the addressing was flawless.
Of course I can live with this solution, but I would like to understand what happened during my first attempt.
If somebody could explain that would be great!

Debug code:

```
 int[][] m_dist = Enumerable.Repeat(Enumerable.Repeat(-1, m.Length).ToArray(), m.Length).ToArray();

 for (int i = 0; i < m_dist.Length; i++)
 {
    for (int j = 0; j < m_dist[i].Length; j++)
    {
       Console.Write(m_dist[i][j] + ",");
    }
    Console.Write("\n");
 }

 Console.WriteLine();

 m_dist[1][1] = 0;

 for ( int i = 0; i< m_dist.Length; i++ )
 {
    for (int j = 0; j < m_dist[i].Length; j++)
    {
       Console.Write(m_dist[i][j] + ",");
    }
    Console.Write("\n");
 }

 Console.WriteLine();
```

Of course I can live with this solution, but I would like to understand what happened during my first attempt.If somebody could explain that would be great!

Comment: obviously because it's the same instance of the array multiple times ... your code is basically `int[] a = new  [] {.... }` ... and then `int[][] aa = new [][] { a, a, a, a, a, a }`

Comment: @Selvin "Obvious" to you but obviously not so obvious to OP. :D

Answer (score 3):

Let me unpack this line so you can see what exactly happens:

```cs
int[][] m_dist = Enumerable.Repeat(Enumerable.Repeat(-1, m.Length).ToArray(), m.Length).ToArray();
```

Unrolling the expressions we get:

```cs
int[] array = Enumerable.Repeat(-1, m.Length).ToArray();
int[][] m_dist = Enumerable.Repeat(array, m.Length).ToArray();
```

You create a single `array` filled with `-1` values, and then create an array `m_dist` that contains *repeated references to that array*. Every entry in `m_dist` points to `array`, so editing an element through any of these references is reflected through all of those references.

What you want to do is create `m.Length` separate arrays:

```cs
int[][] m_dist = Enumerable.Range(0, m.Length)
    .Select(_ => Enumerable.Repeat(-1, m.Length).ToArray())
    .ToArray();
```